# Is there any way to use the laravel Form: model () with an entity of Doctrine?

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine, laravel-form

I recently started a project with Laravel and Doctrine, and I need to use the Laravel `Form::model()` with an entity of the Doctrine. Is it possible? If not, is there any other solution to reuse the same form to create / edit?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you want to have form model binding. Maybe this would help you out https://laracasts.com/lessons/form-model-binding

Comment: Yes, but it has to be with doctrine. how to do this?